# WCAG 2.0 Compliance checker

Tags: wcag2.0

Have a requirement to make website compatible for visually challenged
people (WCAG 2.0 Compliance).
Found an online tool Achecker,but it seems to be not identifying html 5/bootstrap
properties.
It would be helpful if anybody can recommend any online tool to check whether the
changes made to make website compatible with wcag guidelines are correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most popular checker is the WAVE WebAim checker: http://wave.webaim.org/

A stricter checker is Cryptzone's CynthiaSays: http://www.cynthiasays.com/

I use both. I start with WebAim and once I've ironed out those issues I move onto Cryptzone.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for the feedback.
In the wave tool,should we focus on error count to make the website wcag compliant or should we check the alerts too?
 Does The second one cryptzone need to purchased to test in the development environment or can we test a local url with it which is not public? 
Can we test the keyboard accessibility with any tool?
Apart from that,is there any reference sites which is already complianed with wcag 2.0 guidelines?

Comment: In the Wave tool, I would say to focus on both error count and alerts. Their alerts are often WCAG issues.

I believe cryptzone can only test public urls.

I don't know that either is great at testing keyboard accessibility. I just check that one by hand.

There are certainly some wCAG 2.0 compliant websites, especially in the European Union, where it is mandated for some industries. I would suggest Googling for examples; perhaps you can find one in your field.

Comment: One last word of caution: Neither Wave nor Cryptzone catches everything. If you run both, you'll catch most of the errors, but you'll still need to re-read the guidelines and check the site manually at the end. As one example, if your website has Word docs or PDFs for download, neither checker checks to make sure those are formatted in an accessible way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Currently was checking using another tool(https://www.powermapper.com/),but its trial version downloaded has limitation to check the pages.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend the following web accessibility evaluation tools:

**WAVE Web Accessibility Tool**

**Web Accessibility Checker**

**AccessiBe - Automation tool**

to check the website if you want to be more detailed about the code.

However, sometimes evaluation tools may report illogic warnings that is why it's good to also trust your knowledge about WCAG standards and usability for people with disabilities.

For example here (scroll down) [Build a successful website for a small business with WCAG 2.0 compliance with WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accessibe/) you may check WCAG WordPress themes tested with the tools I recommended.

Comment: https://adrianroselli.com/2020/06/accessibe-will-get-you-sued.html